# Bibliotecas em C++

Tags: c++

tenho uma duvida sobre as bibliotecas em C++ que está me martelando a tempo.

É realmente necessário importar por exemplo, a biblioteca math.h para usar as funções como pow e sqrt?
ou a biblioteca locale.h para usar setlocale(LC_ALL,"");?

pois hoje acabei testando sem importar e funcionou do mesmo jeito, gostaria de saber se é certo usar as funções sem importa-las e se isso causa algum "dano" no programa.

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Sim. É necessário. E faltando algo vai receber o aviso de missing reference por parte do LINK e não  via gerar seu programa. No entanto muitas vezes um #include que use já inclui outro que você usou então ele pode parecer supérfluo. Se você usa uma função de b,h e inclui a.h que por acaso inclui b.h pode prescindir do `#include "b.h" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, o correto é sempre importar a biblioteca, as vezes por algum motivo provavelmente por esta executando com o compilador também rodando na maquina o código acaba funcionando. Porém o comportamento normal faz com que ele não funcione e assim prejudicando o projeto. Sendo assim aconselho sempre importar fazer a importação para que seu programa sempre funcione normalmente.